# Mysql 8 with docker return Host '172.xx.x.x' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: docker, mysql-8.0

My problem is a kind of weird.

when I got my containers up I can't connect to my database by any database manager.
I get

```sh
mysql      | 2020-05-11T15:48:56.348312Z 8 [Warning] [MY-010055] [Server] IP address '172.21.0.1' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
```

but after I execute my migrations by terminal with the command above, I can access my database by any database manager normally.

```sh
$ docker-compose exec php-fpm php artisan migrate
```

my docker-compose.yml

```
  #MySQL Service
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network
```

and my 'my.cnf'

```
[mysqld]
general_log = 1
general_log_file = /var/lib/mysql/general.log
secure-file-priv= NULL
#Accept connections from any IP address
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Hi. What command did you run that caused that log above? How (and from where) you were trying to connect to MySQL?

Comment: Hi. I execute "docker-compose up" so when I have all my containers up the terminal still working showing the log. When I tried to access from my database manager, the console shows this error and my db manager says the root@172.xx.x is not allowed.

Comment: Where are you trying to access from? From host or another container?

Comment: From host. As I said from another container as php-laravel it works. After I use it with php-laravel I can access from any host. but at first time that I get all the containers up I can't. I tried with Dberaver and Heidsql and both I got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it updating the mysql version to 8.0.20 and adding the following lines to my "my.cnf" file.

```sh
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
character-set-server=utf8
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

So my file is like that now

```sh
[mysqld]
general_log = 1
general_log_file = /var/lib/mysql/general.log
secure-file-priv= NULL
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
character-set-server=utf8
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Comment: In my case It works only when the container is run second time. That's because the mysql service is restarted after first failure. So mysql loads with new config with bind-address set to 0.0.0.0. How can this be fixed?

Comment: I was facing the same problem. After I've updated the version from 8 to 8.0.20 I got it fixed.

Comment: I had to add `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` to it and it worked out.